# Laravel validation errors doesn't work properly - localization issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-localization

I have several languages on my application and I'm using laravellocalization package (Here is [github page](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization))

Well package works fine, I checked both of `Laravellocalization::getCurrentLocale()` and `App::getLocale()`. Both of them gave me correct locale..

But still when some validation errors occured, it shows error in different languages. Sometimes it uses correct locale but sometimes it shows with not the default locale but `Request::getPreferredLanguage()`

I don't know what causing it and how to I fix it. Log file shows anything, when dump the locales, everything seems just fine..

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you show us any of your code where it breaks?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I don't know what breaks the code and where its happen.. I'm still searching but I don't have any useful material to provide

Comment: IMHO it's better if you open an issue in the library repository, without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is difficult to guess an answer.